# The following sqlite3 comand gives salt the value [object Object] while the database has a string value any ideas why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, hash

```
let salt = db.get(`SELECT salt FROM users WHERE username = ?`, [username]);
```

The database is supposed to return the string that's in the database that was put there with the following code:

```
var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8).toString();
db.run(`INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`, [username, hashString, salt]);
```

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question but couldn't `[object Object]` be the actual result of the statement `var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8).toString()` Your question seems to assume that it isn't ... but have you looked at the data in the database?

Comment: Yes, the value in the database is "839cb5258434e5f578426d7da24490f1"

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet, I'd suggest reviewing [the documentation for `get()`](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#getsql--param---callback), which explicitly mentions that its return value "*is an object containing the values for the first row. The property names correspond to the column names of the result set. It is impossible to access them by column index; the only supported way is by column name.*"

As such, your code should reference the column you wish to extract to your variable:

```
let salt = db.get(`SELECT salt FROM users WHERE username = ?`, [username]).salt;
```

Comment: This doesn't change the outcome, previously I tired db.run but the same thing happens